# How to get the constraint name in a org.springframework.dao.DataIntegrityViolationException?

Tags: java, hibernate, spring

In my application when a violation key is raised, I would like to get the constraint name, but I'm not finding any method to get this information. The message returned by "getMessage()" is very summarized and I need more information about the error to make a customizable error message to the end user.

The stack trace:

```
84732 [http-8080-1] WARN  org.hibernate.util.JDBCExceptionReporter  - SQL Error: 0, SQLState: 23505
84732 [http-8080-1] ERROR org.hibernate.util.JDBCExceptionReporter  - ERROR: duplicate key value violates unique constraint "ix_tb_oferta_vaga"
  Detalhe: Key (cd_pj, cd_curso)=(680, 29) already exists.
187405 [http-8080-1] WARN  org.hibernate.util.JDBCExceptionReporter  - SQL Error: 0, SQLState: 23505
187405 [http-8080-1] ERROR org.hibernate.util.JDBCExceptionReporter  - ERROR: duplicate key value violates unique constraint "ix_tb_oferta_vaga"
  Detalhe: Key (cd_pj, cd_curso)=(680, 29) already exists.
```

The getMessage():

```
could not insert: [br.gov.ce.seduc.estagio.model.bean.OfertaVaga]; nested exception is org.hibernate.exception.ConstraintViolationException: could not insert: [br.gov.ce.seduc.estagio.model.bean.OfertaVaga]
```

Thanks.

Arthur

Answer (score 6, accepted):

Wrapping exceptions usually have a way to nest the original exception within them. For Hibernate, your ConstraintViolationException is a JDBCException, it has a method called [getSQLException](http://docs.jboss.org/hibernate/core/3.2/api/org/hibernate/JDBCException.html#getSQLException%28%29) that returns the actual exception. So call getCause on the Spring DataIntegrityViolationException (in order to get the Hibernate exception), call getSQLException on that, and finally call getMessage() on the SQLException. The message should be the same as what you see logged by the Hibernate JDBCExceptionReporter, if you want only the constraint name you will have to parse the string.

Answer (score 13):

Insert a `catch` statement like this:

```
catch (DataIntegrityViolationException e) {
        String message = e.getMostSpecificCause().getMessage();
}
```

Comment: This will return a string in the format `ERROR: duplicate key value violates unique constraint "uk_meb3tm159kt0clyot5mmv8oht"
  Detail: Key (organization_name)=(Villa College QI Campus) already exists.`. This will not be helpful if they want to provide a message for the end user

Comment: I think the only part that we need to take care is giving meaningful unique constraint names then it will look like: 
`ERROR: duplicate key value violates unique constraint "unique_organization_name" Detail: Key (organization_name)=(Villa College QI Campus) already exists.`

Answer (score 3):

You can handle like that

```
catch (DataIntegrityViolationException ex){
     String constraintName = ((ConstraintViolationException)ex.getCause()).getConstraintName();
 ...
```

But be careful import will be

```
 import org.hibernate.exception.ConstraintViolationException;
```

not

```
 import javax.validaiton;
```

Comment: What about how to get constraint type? i.e. uniqueness error?

Comment: And column name and offending parameter?

Comment: it is most common issue. and it is obvious duplicate key value violates unique constraint in error logs.You can handle PropertyValueException , DataException also. https://www.baeldung.com/spring-dataIntegrityviolationexception

Answer (score 0):

If you are using PostgreSQL and you are really interested to find detailed cause of the exception, then you can use PostgreSQL in compilation time, as so:

```xml
<dependency>
    <groupId>org.postgresql</groupId>
    <artifactId>postgresql</artifactId>
    <!--<scope>runtime</scope>-->
</dependency>
```

This way, you will have utility methods and the PSQLException class. With this, now you can cast most specific cause to it.

```java
var exceptionCause = exception.getMostSpecificCause();

if (exceptionCause instanceof PSQLException psqlException) {
    var serverErrorMessage = psqlException.getServerErrorMessage();

    if (serverErrorMessage != null) {
        var detail = serverErrorMessage.getDetail();
        exceptionCause = new Exception(detail);
    }
}
```

As you can see, now you can throw or handle this `exceptionCause` that will have your detailed or human-readable message.